# Django ver 1.7 AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am trying to work through the authentication tutorials to make sure everything works as expected.
I entered the following code.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
>>> user.last_name = 'Lennon'
>>> user.save()
```

and I get the error

```
AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

I see from the release notes

> The default implementation of `remove()` for `ForeignKey` related
>   managers changed from a series of `Model.save()` calls to a single
>   `QuerySet.update()` call. The change means that `pre_save` and `post_save`
>   signals aren’t sent anymore. You can use the `bulk=False` keyword
>   argument to revert to the previous behaviour.

So I presume it is a foreign key issue.

My question is, where do I use the `bulk=False` attribute or is there another solution?

Answer (score 16):

I suggest doing this before your code above:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

Does that fix it?