# Calling delete() in Django gives error message

Tags: python, django

Let's say in Django I have the model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I then use the following code in the Django Shell:

```
from app.models import Test
test = Test(name = "Hi")
test.save()
```

So far so good. Now I do:

```
Test.objects.all().delete()
```

I then get a very long error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 536, in delete
    collector.collect(del_query)
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 193, in collect
    if self.can_fast_delete(objs):
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 155, in can_fast_delete
    for related in get_candidate_relations_to_delete(opts):
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 67, in <genexpr>
    f for f in candidate_model_fields
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    opts.get_fields(include_hidden=True) for opts in candidate_models
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 740, in get_fields
    return self._get_fields(include_parents=include_parents, include_hidden=include_hidden)
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 802, in _get_fields
    all_fields = self._relation_tree
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 59, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 709, in _relation_tree
    return self._populate_directed_relation_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 681, in _populate_directed_relation_graph
    all_models = self.apps.get_models(include_auto_created=True)
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 168, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

I have seen other people get a similar error message, but they were not using the delete() operation nor were they using the Django shell. If it is relevant, I am using Django 1.8.6 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26215548/4708186) SO [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25940469/4708186) that I've seen, this will do the trick:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

and the reason behind it is

> Basically, Django has a new way to load installed app. If you load
>   Django from a Python script (like I was in my custom unit tests), some
>   initialization needs to be done before proceeding and calling setup()
>   is how to do it. Aside from that, kudos to the team, my 1.6.2 to 1.7.1
>   upgrade seems to an hour's worth of real work.
>
> – JL Peyret